# Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I am trying to create a WCF Service with only Transport Security so I do not need SSL.

I keep geting this error message when I run it:

```
Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding 
BasicHttpBinding.
```

My Web.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>      
        <binding name="Binding1">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>      
      </basicHttpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="AutoSenderWCFService.AutoSenderService">        
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="Binding1"
          contract="AutoSenderWCFService.IService1" />        
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceCredentials>

            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
              customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="AutoSenderWCFService.MyValidator, AutoSenderWCFService"/>

          </serviceCredentials>

          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transport security means securing your channel with SSL and hence you would need a certificate.

If you dont want to use SSL but want to pass username password over the channel then you can use [**ClearUsernameBinding**](http://webservices20.blogspot.co.uk/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html) that sends the username password over the channel in clear text.

NOTE: Make sure you use this only when you are confident that you client and server channel is secure like behind a firewall that provides security.

Answer (score 1):

I cant see any address in there - add an address to your endpoint and should be ok

so:

```
<endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" address="https://address" bindingConfiguration="Binding1" 
          contract="AutoSenderWCFService.IService1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying to test a wcf web service setup on a testing server without ssl. I changed the security mode to none and it started working for me.